# Why is $\varphi: R[A] \to S$ automatically an $R$-module homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, modules, proof-explanation

From *Algebra: Chapter $0$* by Aluffi:

> [image]
>   [image]

---

I'm pretty sure $$\varphi(\sum m_{i_1 \cdots i_n} x_1^{i_1} \cdots x_n^{i_n})= \sum \alpha(m_{i_1 \cdots i_n}) f(1)^{i_1} \cdots f(n)^{i_n}.$$

So, we have
\begin{align*}
\varphi(r\sum m_{i_1 \cdots i_n} x_1^{i_1} \cdots x_n^{i_n})
&= \varphi(\sum rm_{i_1 \cdots i_n} x_1^{i_1} \cdots x_n^{i_n})\\
&=\sum \alpha(rm_{i_1 \cdots i_n}) f(1)^{i_1} \cdots f(n)^{i_n}\\
&= \sum \alpha(r)\alpha(m_{i_1 \cdots i_n}) f(1)^{i_1} \cdots f(n)^{i_n}\\
&=\alpha(r) \sum \alpha(m_{i_1 \cdots i_n}) f(1)^{i_1} \cdots f(n)^{i_n}\\
&=\alpha(r) \varphi(\sum m_{i_1 \cdots i_n} x_1^{i_1} \cdots x_n^{i_n})
\end{align*}

> How do we show 
>   $$\varphi(r\sum m_{i_1 \cdots i_n} x_1^{i_1} \cdots x_n^{i_n})= r\varphi(\sum m_{i_1 \cdots i_n} x_1^{i_1} \cdots x_n^{i_n})?$$

How is this automatic?

Comment: Because for $r\in R$ and $s\in S$ by definition we have $r\cdot s = \alpha(r)s$ (the $R$-module structure of $S$ is induced by the ring homomorphism). However, $\varphi(r)=\alpha(r)$ and so you are done as $\varphi$ is a ring homomorphism (and therefore multiplicative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'pretty sure' line proves it - which is indeed true -, using that $\alpha$ is a ring homomorphism:
$$\varphi(rmx_1^{i_1}\dots x_n^{i_n}) =\alpha(rm)\varphi(x_1^{i_1}\dots x_n^{i_n}) =\alpha(r)\cdot\alpha(m) \varphi(x_1^{i_1}\dots x_n^{i_n})=\alpha(r)\cdot \varphi(m\, x_1^{i_1}\dots x_n^{i_n}) $$

Comment: ...and by definition, if $\alpha: R \to S$ is a ring hom, then the action of $R$ on $S$ induced by $\varphi$ is $r\cdot s= \alpha(r)s$. So, $\alpha(r)\cdot \varphi(m\, x_1^{i_1}\dots x_n^{i_n})=r\cdot \varphi(m\, x_1^{i_1}\dots x_n^{i_n})$.